# Events are not triggering on click of text, when text is made using format message react-intl

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I am using formatted message for context menu  in `Reactjs`. But the click event is not triggering if we click on the text,but outside the text the event is triggering

```
import React from 'react';

import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';

const contextMenu = (props) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li onClick={(event) => props.clicked(event, "edit")}> 
                  <FormattedMessage id={`dm.edit`}/>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default contextMenu;
```

Comment: can you please add the code, where you define the clicked function, which you send via props

Comment: Can you provide working code example?